# Gradle : Package not found

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I just started using Android Studio and is having the package not found error.

I've tried placing the `.jars` in the appropriate folders, "Add as Library", add in gradle.build and cleaning it yet every single time I try to compile it again, it just says "package does not exist"

Image:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Move the libs folder at same level of src folder:

```
 - libs
 - src
   -main
     - java
     - res
```